# How to add an expression to a already existing datacolumn in a datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable, datacolumn

I am able to add an expression while adding a column to a datatable but now i need to add update the expression of an existing datacolumn in a datatable..

How do i do it ?

```
      foreach (DataColumn col in this.dv.ToTable().Columns)
            {
                 if (col.ColumnName == "tot")
               {
                    col.Expression = string.Empty;
                     col.Expression = "description";

                }
            }
```

this piece of code doesnt seem to be working.. 
how do i accomplish this ?

Comment: Why not? What happens? _What error do you get_?

Comment: Fixed the issue.. it should have been this.dv.Table().Columns instead of this.dv.ToTable().Columns the ToTable returns a new table always instead of a reference to the underlying datatable.